# Solving stochastic differential equation $ dX_t = \kappa(\theta - X_t)dt\ +\ \sigma dW_t $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

How do I solve this stochastic differential equation ? I can't seem to get rid of $ X_t.$  Thank you

$ dX_t = \kappa(\theta - X_t)dt\ +\ \sigma dW_t $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the substitution: $Y_t = X_t  e^{kt}$.

Comment: it is mean reveting SDE, and it has an analytic solution